# GStreamer: get child element from GstElement*

Tags: gstreamer

In my code, I currently have a pipeline description that is a string. I use `gst_parse_launch(...)` to utilize this pipeline and everything is working great.

However, now I am interested in setting some properties on one of the elements in the pipeline. Specifically the pipeline sink element (in my case `autovideosink`). I would like the set the property `enable-last-sample` but the `autovideosink` doesn't have that property. Thus my question is, how can I determine which video sink the `autovideosink` has resolved to so I can set this property?

My application is written in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`autovideosink` implements the `GstChildProxy` interface:

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/gstchildproxy.html?gi-language=c

You should be able to set things directly via this interface, or hook into the callbacks directly when a new child is being added.

Answer (score 1):

One way to find out what it resolved to is to use the awesome [pipeline graph debug feature](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/debugging-tools.html?gi-language=c#getting-pipeline-graphs). For example:

```
GST_DEBUG_BIN_TO_DOT_FILE(yourPipeline, GST_DEBUG_GRAPH_SHOW_ALL, file_name)
```

See [GST_DEBUG_BIN_TO_DOT_FILE](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/debugutils.html?gi-language=c#GST_DEBUG_BIN_TO_DOT_FILE) for details.

You can then render that graphviz graph and inspect your pipeline (including all bin-children).

Comment: This is great, thank you! Do you know of any way to do this at runtime?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. This is code, so it will run at run-time.

Comment: I guess I was looking for a way to use this information to make a decision about the pipeline at runtime. It seems that the way to do that with this function is to: 
1. Write the dot file using this function.
2. Read/Parse the dot file.
3. Make decisions based on parsed pipeline information.

Is that what you were suggesting?